# How to format a code in a comment

Tags: support, stack-overflow, code-formatting

When you want to add a comment you get this:

> Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com) *italic* **bold** `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work

I just don't know where to find this: ` symbol in my keyboard, I tried every button but still no luck.
can somebody tell me how to add it to format a code.

Comment: What kind of keyboard do you have?

Comment: you can always do `alt + 096` on your numpad to generate it.

Comment: @Oded what do you mean? and how can I get the type of keyboard?

Comment: `` wow it is working thank you @rene

Comment: I mean, is it a specific country/language one? Like French, UK, US? On my UK keyboard, the backtick is on the same button as the pipe is.

Comment: Have a look here and choose one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout

Comment: I guess it is the Colemak keyboard layout but I'm not so sure.

Comment: It looks like it is left of the 1 on a Colemak board.

Comment: You mean the broken bar right @Oded..? The pipe is bottom left on a UK QWERTY keyboard (I really hope I haven't been wrong all this time!)

Comment: oh that's right. I pressed it previously but it gave me some weird letter. now it is working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had no idea I had it on my keyboard before SO either.

Kind of embarrassing for me.

Here it is on EN-US on a standard English keyboard.

[image]

Comment: That's because Markdown is the only thing I've ever seen that gives backtick a specific meaning.

Comment: MySQL @Robert :-(. It's for quoted identifiers... and it's horrible when people don't use code tags.

Comment: I stand corrected.